# How to Make MediaWiki Api call to get thumbnail image and title from coordinates

Tags: mediawiki

I am making a media wiki web call from iOS device with format -

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&gsradius=10000&gscoord=%@%@%@&list=geosearch&gslimit=500&format=json", [latitude stringValue],@"|",[longitude stringValue]];
```

But this give me results with only "title" and "distance from coordinates",
and i want "title","distance from coordinates" and image url of image on the page corresponding to title .
does such a web call exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`geosearch` list](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData#list.3Dgeosearch) as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) and then get the [pageimage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages) from it:

```
…?action=query&prop=pageimages&pilimit=500&generator=geosearch&ggsradius=10000&ggscoord=%@%@%@&ggslimit=500&format=json
```

Comment: but it never gave distance tag,so i am back to square one

Comment: Uh, right. However, you could use `prop=pageimages|coordinates`, and compute the distance yourself. Or you do two queries and get the `pageimages` separately for each 50-pages-chunk.